# Is GeoServer getting coordinate output in GeoJSON WFS wrong?

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, geojson, wfs

When I do a WFS request to GeoServer and specify the SRS like this:

```
http://myserver.com/geoserver/wfs?
    service=WFS&
    version=2.0.0&
    request=GetFeature&
    outputFormat=application/json&
    srsName=EPSG:4326&
    typeName=MYWORKSPACE:mylayer&
```

I get exactly what I expect and it works fine.

When I remove the `srsName=EPSG:4326` parameter I get GeoJSON that still identifies itself with:

```
"crs": {
    "type": "EPSG",
    "properties": {
        "code": "4326"
    }
}
```

but the order of the coordinates is reversed, so it doesn't work.

Are both of these valid EPSG:4326 output, or is one of them wrong?

The layer I'm working with has these settings:

- **Native SRS:** EPSG:4283
- **Declared SRS:** EPSG:4326
- **SRS handling:** Reproject native to declared

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that Geoserver confirms to the WFS Spec, which specifies the coordinate order like as;
  WFS 1.0.0 - longitude/latitude (x/y) 
  WFS 1.1.0 - latitude/longitude (y/x) 
  WFS 2.0.0 - latitude/longitude (y/x)

See http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/basics.html#axis-ordering

I'm using Leaflet. Switching to WFS 1.0.0 was way easier than some messy javascript workaround.

Comment: Hello. How do you switch to WFS 1.0.0?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes they are both valid - which one you want depends on which version of the coordinate system and OGC standards you are using. See [this page](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/order.html) for a full discussion of the issues.

If you want to be sure of the order of your coordinates don't use epsg:4326 - check out the OGC URN's mentioned at the bottom of that page so you can be sure of what you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a [bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-2397) in GeoServer.

GeoServer in it's WFS implementation specifies the order of coordinates for different versions and projection definitions ([link](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/basics.html#axis-ordering)) but GeoJSON states specifically that the order is always the same (x,y,z or lon,lat,alt). See the [spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions).